# How to make iOS universal links working with Vite + CRA. Vite seems to redirect url when apple-app-site-association file when it isn't .json

Tags: ios, create-react-app, vite, ios-universal-links, apple-app-site-association

I'm using CRA which was migrated to Vite. Im uploading apple-app-site-association file (without .json extension) by placing it in public folder. Vite is building this file because it can read it later if I add .json extension. So can can read it like https://.com/apple-app-site-association.json

But according to apple docs: "Don’t append .json to the apple-app-site-association filename." and when I save Don’t append .json to the apple-app-site-association file and build the app, the url https://.com/apple-app-site-association redirecting to "/". Any idea what I did wrong?